# no overload matches 'Array(Person)#+' with type Person

Tags: crystal-lang

So I just started learning Crystal because I like both Ruby and C, but I just can't get the hang of the syntax yet. I think I am close, but I'm stuck with this error.
    `no overload matches 'Array(Person)#+' with type Person 
Overloads are:
- Array(T)#+(other : Array(U))
people += Person.new("Person#{id}")`

Here is the code.

```
class Person
    def initialize(name : String)
        @name = name
        @age = 0
    end

    def name
        @name
    end

    def age
        @age
    end
end

people = [] of Person
counter = 0
id = 0

loop do
    id+=1
    people += Person.new("Person#{id}")

    counter+=1
    break if counter = 5
end

puts(people)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to put together an Array and a Person. But you can add [Array to Array only.](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.24.1/Array.html#%2B%28other%3AArray%28U%29%29forallU-instance-method)

To solve it, you should use `Array#<<`, like this:
`people << Person.new("Person#{id}")`

**NOTE:** Check your line 25, it should be `break if counter == 5`

Comment: And that's exactly the same behaviour as in Ruby: `+` concats two arrays, `<<` appends an element.

Comment: Solved it for me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

I see your answer was answered,
but because of crystals awesomeness i think it is worth mentioning that all your provided code can also be written as:

```
class Person
  getter name, age = 0
  def initialize(@name : String); end
end

puts Array.new(5) { |i| Person.new("Person#{i + 1}") }
```

Awesome right? :D

The `getter` is a macro defined in the `Object` class, which is a superclass of every class.

And

```
 def initialize(@name)
 end
```

Is just the same as writing

```
 def initialize(name)
   @name = name
 end
```

And there's this neat little line:

```
Array.new(5) { |i| Person.new("Person#{i + 1}") }
```

`Array.new(5)` creates an empty array, and yields every integer from and including 0, up to and not including 5. Therefore, the previously empty arrays index of the number passed, is assigned to the value returned by the block.
So we create a person with the index plus 1 in the block, and since the last value in the block becomes the return value, unless `return` is used, the array index of `i`'s value becomes the new person.

---

Whether to write

```
def initialize(@name); end
```

Or

```
def initialize(@name)
end
```

Is just your personal preferences

Comment: Definitely awesome!

Comment: And `puts Array.new(5) { |i| Person.new("Person#{i + 1}") }` would output the same as the whole second part (the part after the class) :D